# Optimistic lock with RoR and oracle

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oracle, orm

I am using rubyonrails 3.2 with oracle. 
My table have an optimistic column so I added

`self.locking_column = 'my_col'`

in the model.

When I try to update a record, I can see the `WHERE my_col = 42` but ror also try to set the new value (`SET my_col = 43)`, which oracle does not accept (it update the value itself).

How can I make ror to not set the new value?

Comment: what do you mean "oracle does not accept"?

Comment: OCIError: ORA-20001: RVN trigger: Application may not update my_col

Answer (score 0):

An error in the ORA-20000..20999 range is a user application error - in this case, there will be a trigger with some code that raises this error.